# Xamarin.forms Build Error "aapt.exe" exited with code -1073741819

Tags: android, msbuild, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am Using **Xamarin.Forms**, But I updated the Android SD Manager from **eclipse** then I get the following Error:

> Xamarin.forms Build Error "aapt.exe" exited with code -1073741819

Error occurred on the following file: 
\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets

```
<!-- Run aapt to generate R.java -->
    <Aapt Condition="'$(_AndroidResourceDesignerFile)' != ''"
        ImportsDirectory="$(_LibraryProjectImportsDirectoryName)"
        OutputImportDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)__library_projects__\"
        UseShortFileNames="$(UseShortFileNames)"
        JavaPlatformJarPath="$(JavaPlatformJarPath)"
        ManifestFile="$(ResgenTemporaryDirectory)\AndroidManifest.xml"
        PackageName="$(_AndroidPackage)"
        ApplicationName="$(_AndroidPackage)"
        ResourceDirectory="$(MonoAndroidResDirIntermediate)"
        JavaDesignerOutputDirectory="$(ResgenTemporaryDirectory)"
        ResourceOutputFile="$(ResgenTemporaryDirectory)\resources.apk"
        ExtraPackages="$(AaptExtraPackages)"
        AdditionalResourceDirectories="@(LibraryResourceDirectories)"
        LibraryProjectJars="@(ExtractedJarImports)"
        ExtraArgs="$(AndroidResgenExtraArgs)"
        ToolPath="$(AaptToolPath)"
        ToolExe="$(AaptToolExe)"
        AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths="@(_AdditonalAndroidResourceCachePaths)"
        ApiLevel="$(_AndroidTargetSdkVersion)"
        AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk="$(AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk)"
        ResourceNameCaseMap="$(_AndroidResourceNameCaseMap)"
        ExplicitCrunch="$(AndroidExplicitCrunch)"
    />
```

```
  <Aapt
    ImportsDirectory="$(_LibraryProjectImportsDirectoryName)"
    OutputImportDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)__library_projects__\"
    UseShortFileNames="$(UseShortFileNames)"
    JavaPlatformJarPath="$(JavaPlatformJarPath)"
    ManifestFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\AndroidManifest.xml"
    ResourceDirectory="$(MonoAndroidResDirIntermediate)"
    JavaDesignerOutputDirectory="$(AaptTemporaryDirectory)"
    ResourceOutputFile="$(_PackagedResources)"
    ExtraPackages="$(AaptExtraPackages)"
    AdditionalResourceDirectories="@(LibraryResourceDirectories)"
    ExtraArgs="$(AndroidResgenExtraArgs)"
    PackageName="$(_AndroidPackage)"
    ApplicationName="$(_AndroidPackage)"
    UncompressedFileExtensions="$(AndroidStoreUncompressedFileExtensions)"
    AssetDirectory="$(MonoAndroidAssetsDirIntermediate)"
    ToolPath="$(AaptToolPath)"
    ToolExe="$(AaptToolExe)"
    AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths="@(_AdditonalAndroidResourceCachePaths)"
    ApiLevel="$(_AndroidTargetSdkVersion)"
    AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk="$(AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk)"
    ResourceNameCaseMap="$(_AndroidResourceNameCaseMap)"
    SupportedAbis="$(_BuildTargetAbis)"
    CreatePackagePerAbi="$(AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi)"
    ExplicitCrunch="$(AndroidExplicitCrunch)"
     />
```

Comment: Are you having dashes `-` in your image filenames?

Comment: actually no I have not  :(

Comment: This post might help.https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28181/android-build-tools-21-0-1-aapt-exe-exited-with-code-1073741819-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that you've got the right target SDK framework levels installed in the SDK Manager. I've seen similar errors during build when some of them are missing.

Comment: maybe , i copy sdk manager from other pc to my pc and this resolved an issue .. thanks